# How to use yyextra in C++?

Tags: flex-lexer

I would like to access an external struct, within the scanner rules. When using C language, yyextra is provided as solution for this. Apparently yyextra is not available when generating a C++ scanner.
What's the proper solution to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive your own lexer class from `yyFlexLexer` and add whatever you want to it.

If you do this, you will probably want to tell Flex the name of your class:

```
%option yyclass="myLexer"
```

See the description of [this option](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options.html#index-_002d_002d_002dyyclass):

> `‘--yyclass=NAME, %option yyclass="NAME"’`
>
> …informs flex that you have derived `NAME` as a subclass of `yyFlexLexer`, so flex will place your actions in the member function `NAME::yylex()` instead of `yyFlexLexer::yylex()`.…

and the [note about the `yylex()`](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx) member function:

> `virtual int yylex()`
>
>
> performs the same role is `yylex()` does for ordinary flex scanners: it scans the input stream, consuming tokens, until a rule’s action returns a value. If you derive a subclass `S` from `yyFlexLexer` and want to access the member functions and variables of `S` inside `yylex()`, then you need to use `%option yyclass="S"` to inform flex that you will be using that subclass instead of `yyFlexLexer`. In this case, rather than generating `yyFlexLexer::yylex()`, flex generates `S::yylex()` (and also generates a dummy `yyFlexLexer::yylex()` that calls `yyFlexLexer::LexerError()` if called).

Comment: indeed I came to the same solution in the meanwhile :) the documentation is a bit hard to read but it contained all the information

Comment: @HAL9000: Then I hope this answer is easier to read than the documentation, even though it quotes extensively from it :)

Comment: the answer seems to contain all the needed information, thanks!